Unable to access properties of object in react
I am unable to access the properties of user_daily_status.
This var contains an object which is displayed as below...
However, when i am trying to access user_daily_status._id I am getting error as TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
function getUserStatus(username) {
    const status = dailyStatus.find(function (ds) {
      if (ds.username === username) {
        console.log(ds);
        return ds;
      }
      // return ds.username == username;
    });
    return status;
  }

Code Snippet :
{users.map((user, index) => {
        console.log(user);
        let user_daily_status = getUserStatus(user);
        console.log(user_daily_status._id);

        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{user}</td>
            <td>{console.log(user_daily_status)}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}



user_daily_status = {
        "_id": "669d3c92fd117c2db8492d4d",
        "username": "test",
        "date": "21/7/2024",
        "status": [
            {
                "tag": "tag1",
                "status": "test333",
                "_id": "669d3c92fd117c2db8492d4e"
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag2",
                "status": "11",
                "_id": "669d3c92fd117c2db8492d4f"
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag3",
                "status": "sbbbd",
                "_id": "669d3c92fd117c2db8492d50"
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag4",
                "status": "sssss",
                "_id": "669d3c92fd117c2db8492d51"
            },
            {
                "tag": "tag5",
                "status": "sss",
                "_id": "669d3c92fd117c2db8492d52"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }




The error means that wherever you're referencing user_daily_status, it is not defined. Exactly why that is could be a variety of things, but nobody can say exactly if you don't add the relevant code to your question.

@Pointy, I have added the code snippet

OK well what does getUserStatus() look like?

updated.........

OK well if the username is not found in the array, the function returns undefined.

@Pointy, its found...

I don't think it is, because you're getting the error that led you to post this question.

The issue is in the find function's callback. If the condition is met, it should return true, not ds... And return false otherwize. See MDN .find() -- And Pointy is right... It can return undefined... So you should take this possibility in account.

Why not check to see first that the  user_daily_status is not undefined before trying to access _id

It looks like getUserStatus(user) is returning undefined, which means user_daily_status is undefined and hence you can't access _id on it. Here’s how you can troubleshoot and fix it:


function getUserStatus(username) {
  const status = dailyStatus.find(ds => ds.username === username);
  return status;
}

{users.map((user, index) => {
  const user_daily_status = getUserStatus(user);
  console.log(user_daily_status); // Check what is logged here

  return (
    <tr key={index}>
      <td>{user}</td>
      <td>{user_daily_status ? user_daily_status._id : 'No status'}</td>
    </tr>
  );
})}



